Type Mismatch (PowerPoint Office 365 VBA)
Sample code:
Sub CreateSlides()
'Open the Excel workbook. Change the filename here.
Dim OWB As Excel.Workbook
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\willi\OneDrive\Documents\EDU\Spanish\Vocab-test.xlsx")
'Grab the first Worksheet in the Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim sCurrentText As String
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Set WS = OWB.Worksheets(1)
Dim i As Long
'Loop through each used row in Column A
For i = 1 To WS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    'Copy the first slide and paste at the end of the presentation
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1)

At this last statement (Set oS1) I get a type mismatch error.  This is code I copied from a source that I believe actually used it; however, I have questions since I don't know where the variable "Count" comes from.
I am running Office 365 on a Dell (W11) laptop.
Suggestions
I step through the code and get the error message on this statement.



"I don't know where the variable "Count" comes from" >>  It's not a variable, it's a property of the presentation's Slides collection object; it tells you how many slides are in the presentation. Rather than copy/pasting slides (can cause timing issues), why not use: Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate(1)



Thanks - the code now runs without error, doesn't do everything I need, but think I can take it to the next step.  Thanks for your support.

Glad to help. And so ... what's it not doing that you want it to do? Maybe we can help with that too. I'm guessing something like: Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate(1) [add new line here]
oSl.MoveTo ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

You are right.  I want to move the duplicated slide to the end of the deck.  Also, I want to skip any rows that are hidden.

The bit of code in my last comment should do exactly that.  As to hidden rows, you'll need to test for that just before copying the first slide.

This code snipet runs, but does not detect the hidden rows.  What am I missing?
Din rng as Range
Set rng = WS.Range("A65536")
rng.Select
'Loop through each used row in Column B
For i = 1 To WS.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
If rng.EntireRow(i).Hidden = True Then
    GoTo HR
End If


If you know the row numbers of the rows you want to test, you could adapt something like this:  Sub Test()
Dim x As Long
Dim oWs As Worksheet
Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
With oWs
For x = 1 To 5
If .Rows(x).Hidden Then
MsgBox x
End If
Next
End With
End Sub

The statement 'If rng.EntireRow(i).Hidden = True' always retuned a False value.  The statement 'If .Rows(i).Hidden Then" works.  Home free!  Thanks.
